# MobileDragAndDrop Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I am currently working with a jquery lib named mobiledraganddrop.
Now i want to add Drag elements dynamically with java script
This is the Code for HTML.

```
<div data-role="panel" id="right-panel" data-position=right
        data-display=overlay data-theme="c">
        <form id="fdad">
            <div style="width: 200px;">
                <div class="drag" id="drag1">
                    <p>P1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="drag" id="drag2">
                    <p>P2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="drag" id="drag3">
                    <p>P3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Now i want the same with Javascript but it does not work....

```
var parent = document.getElementById("fdad");
var element = document.createElement("drag");
element.setAttribute("id", "1");
element.setAttribute("name", "blaa");
parent.appendChild(element);
```

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure how the plugin works, but try something like:

```
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.className = "drag";
element.id = "drag1";
```

Or using jQuery:

```
$('#fdad').append('<div class="drag" id="drag1">');
```